# How to modify dict elements based on key value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I struggle with some basic idea (I guess)

```
list_a = [{'title': 'some product name ()', 'network': 'network_one'}, {'title': 'another product name - some more', 'network': 'network_two'}]

keys_dict = {
    'network_one': items['title'].split('(')[0].title().rstrip(), #yup - I know its wrong but you have the idea
    'network_two': items['title'].split('-')[0].lower().rstrip(),
}

l = []
for items in list_a:
    # print(i)
    if items['network'] in keys_dict:
        items['product'] = keys_dict[items['network']]
        l.append(items)
print(l)
```

Given is a list_a;

I want o to create new key 'product' based on 'network' key values from list_a. So if the 'network' == 'network_one', 'product' value should be created by applying

```
split('(')[0].title().rstrip()
```

on 'title' value

Different 'title' string transformations based on another key value and creating new key, value from it.

Simple if,else does work here for me but when you have plenty of data; I guess it's easier to manage when you use dicts.

Expected output =

```
l = [{'title': 'some product name ()', 'network': 'network_one', 'product: 'Some product name'}, {'title': 'another product name - some more', 'network': 'network_two', 'product': 'another product name'}]
```

A simple strings as a new values like below does work but and I know how to handle them I have no idea of how to apply the above scenario where the key values have to (?) be strings modification values rstrip etc

```
keys_dict = {
    'network_one': 'product name', 
    'network_two': 'another product name',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda function in your keys_dict that should take a string as argument and does the appropriate conversion.

```
keys_dict = {
    'network_one': lambda s: s.split('(')[0].title().rstrip(),
    'network_two': lambda s: s.split('-')[0].lower().rstrip(),
}

new_list = []
for d in list_a:
    if (network := d['network']) in keys_dict:
        d['product'] = keys_dict[network](d['title'])
        new_list.append(d)
```

Comment: does the job. Thanks

Comment: could you explain what this command do: if (network := d['network']) ?

Comment: @Michal This is an assignment expression. Within if statement I'm assigning value to a variable named network so that I can use its value later on easily. If you are not comfortable with this you can simplify it as `network = d['network']` next-line `if network in keys_dict`. More info on this: https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/

Answer (score 0):

i would use `re` for this task:

```
from re import search

list_a = [{'title': 'some product name ()', 'network': 'network_one'}, 
          {'title': 'another product name - some more', 'network': 'network_two'}]

for d in list_a:
    d['product'] = search(r'^(.*) [(-]?',d['title'])[1]

>>> list_a
'''
[{'title': 'some product name ()',
  'network': 'network_one',
  'product': 'some product name'},
 {'title': 'another product name - some more',
  'network': 'network_two',
  'product': 'another product name'}]
```

Comment: edit - it does not work when I have different value transformations for each key. You r code assumes that we have to look for both ( and - in title. In reality - its not truth here. We modify 'title' value based on different 'network' values

Comment: @Michal could you add the example of value transformation to your question?

Comment: its already there - Expected output. But its just two examples of network value here. I have to change based on network value (which can be different and I can have 100s of them) and a lambda solution given by Firelord is better here.

Comment: _'You r code assumes that we have to look for both ( and - in title'_ actualy not both but one of, because this syntax`[ ]` means that characters can be listed individually. more about re syntax [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)